# How to prevent selection of an object after creation on fabricjs canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an object that on click generates an image on my canvas. How can I disable selection on this generated image object?

I added the following in my code: `canvas.selection = false;`
This disables selection on the object with the click function but for any new image object that is added, it doesn't work.

Example (click the smallest blue dot): https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/yLVbvGb
You can't move the blue dot, but the images that get added can be moved.

I've tried adding the following line: `printzelf.selection = false` in the function where the image gets created but this still doesn't work. I've also tried adding `selection: false` alongside the parameters, but no success.

```
savebtnclick.onclick = function() {
  var imgURL = 'https://printzelf.nl/new/assets/images/logo_gewoon.png';
  var printzelfImg = new Image();
  printzelfImg.onload = function (img) {
    var printzelf = new fabric.Image(printzelfImg, {
    width: 350,
    height: 100,
    left: 450,
    top: 70,
    scaleX: .25,
    scaleY: .25,
    id: 'testimg',
    selection: false
    });
    canvas.add(printzelf);
    printzelf.selection = false;
  };
  printzelfImg.src = imgURL;
}
```

How can I disable the selection for everything? Including newly added objects? Changing it into a static canvas is not an option because I lose too many functions.

Comment: You're talking about the selection of 'Testtest'?

Comment: @obscure No, the selection of the image (printzelf) that is added when clicking the blue dot. You can resize it, move it etc. I want to disable that whole selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fabric.js offers a property for it's Image class called [selectable](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#selectable).
If set to **false** you can't move/rotate/scale an image.

```
  printzelfImg.onload = function (img) {
    var printzelf = new fabric.Image(printzelfImg, {
    width: 350,
    height: 100,
    left: 450,
    top: 70,
    scaleX: .25,
    scaleY: .25,
    id: 'testimg',
    selectable: false
    });
    canvas.add(printzelf);
    printzelf.selection = false;
  };
```